# Alternatives to python griddata

Tags: python, scipy, resampling

I am using griddata to resample a numpy 2 dimensional array on a grid.

```
z.shape = (1000, 1000)
x, y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.01), np.arange(-5, 5, 0.01)
newx, newy = np.arange(-2, 2, 0.1), np.arange(-2, 2, 0.1)

griddata((x, y), z, (newx[None, :], newy[:, None]))
```

The code should:

- resample z (which represents an image) to a new *coarser* or *finer* grid
- the new grid does not necessarily cover all of the original one.

However griddata cannot manage a regular input grid. Does anyone know an easy alternative?

Comment: Can you explain `manage a regular input grid`?

Comment: @wwii Hi, I meant that griddata cannot use a rectangular grid, where x and y coordinates are aligned. This I think because it uses triangulation.

Answer (score 2):

Use any of the methods suitable for data on a grid listed in the documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html#multivariate-interpolation

That is:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.html

or https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.html

or https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.map_coordinates.html

Note also that you are using `griddata` incorrectly. Your code corresponds to interpolating from a line defined by your 1000 (x, y) coordinates, where each point has 1000 values associated with it. However, interpolation to 2D from a 1D line is badly defined, and the failure results from trying to triangulate a set of points that are along a line.

You should do

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

z = np.random.rand(100, 100)
z.shape = (100, 100)
x, y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1), np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='ij')

newx, newy = np.arange(-2, 2, 0.1), np.arange(-2, 2, 0.1)

griddata((xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()), z.ravel(), (newx[None, :], newy[:, None]))
```

This will work correctly --- however, 1000x1000 = 1000000 points in 2D is simply way too much data for triangulation-based unstructured interpolation (needs large amounts of memory for the triangulation + it's slow), so you should use the gridded data algorithms.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and for pointing out the error in my example too (embarrassing).

Comment: I plan to update your answer by showing how I used RectBivariateSpline. Do you mind if I do? You could always revert, I think.