# Python - Equivalent to scipy griddata because of an error

Tags: datagrid, scipy, interpolation

I would like to use an equivalent to scipy griddata because of an error appears :

```
QH7074 qhull warning: more than 16777215 ridges.  ID field overflows and two ridges
may have the same identifier.  Otherwise output ok.
```

which sometimes kill my calculation or just very slow...

Currently i have :

```
test_interp= griddata((xx_points.flatten(),yy_points.flatten()),values.flatten(), (xi+X,yi+V), method='linear',fill_value=nan)
```

Comment: I think it s due to the importance of value to treat... :/

Comment: If your original data is on a rectangular grid, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26276550/alternatives-to-python-griddata/26282370

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error message and it looks like a limitation of `griddata` for big data, according to this [thread](https://github.com/PaulHancock/Aegean/issues/14). The limit is 2^24=16777216 'ridges' (I don't know exactly what it refers to). I did exactly the same interpolation with less data points and this problem didn't occur. My guess is that you should find a way to split your dataset to be below the 2^24 threshold.